# Page scrolling up when using Bootstrap and AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am writing a HTML page using Bootstrap and AngularJS to capture details of an order, and when the page has finished loading it jumps up so that the header of the panel is hidden under the bootstrap navbar.

This isn't what I was expecting.  See this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/WJolkMctu9V2sOtlvmUt) for an example of what I want to achieve.  It shows the panel header and the focus is on the `Order Ref` field as expected and the page doesn't move up at all.

I have tried to create a plunkr that uses AngularJS to demonstrate the issue, but I couldn't get it to run properly so I decided to show the same plunked code in the hope that someone has come across this before.

```
<!-- Orders.html -->

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" charset="utf-8" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="site.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <title>Portal</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header class="bs">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" rel="home" href="#">Portal</a>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                    <div class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <div class="navbar-text">Search</div>
                        <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="srch-term" id="srch-term" type="text">
                                <div class="input-group-btn">
                                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
      <form name="form" class="form-horizontal" confirm-on-exit>
          <div class="panel panel-primary">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                  Create New Order
              </div>
              <div class="panel-body">
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="inputOrderRef3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Order Ref</label>
                      <div class="col-sm-10">
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputOrderRef3" placeholder="Order Ref" ng-model="order.orderRef" maxlength="6" required autofocus>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="inputOrderDate3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Order Date</label>
                      <div class="col-sm-10">
                          <input type="date" class="form-control" id="inputOrderDate3" ng-model="order.orderDate" required>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="inputCustomer3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Customer</label>
                      <div class="col-sm-10">
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputCustomer3" placeholder="Customer" ng-model="order.customerName" maxlength="50" required>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="inputOrderedBy3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Ordered By</label>
                      <div class="col-sm-10">
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputOrderedBy3" placeholder="Ordered By" ng-model="order.orderedBy" maxlength="3" required>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="inputInstallationDate3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Installation Date</label>
                      <div class="col-sm-10">
                          <input type="date" class="form-control" id="inputInstallationDate3" ng-model="order.installationDate" required>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="inputAddress3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Address</label>
                      <div class="col-sm-10">
                          <textarea id="inputAddress3" class="form-control" rows="4" ng-model="order.address" maxlength="250" required></textarea>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="inputTown3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Town</label>
                      <div class="col-sm-10">
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputTown3" placeholder="Town" ng-model="order.town" maxlength="30" required>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="inputPostcode3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Postcode</label>
                      <div class="col-sm-10">
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputPostcode3" placeholder="Postcode" ng-model="order.postcode" maxlength="15" required>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="inputOrderNumber3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Order Number</label>
                      <div class="col-sm-10">
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputOrderNumber3" placeholder="Order Number" ng-model="order.orderNumber" required>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="inputValue3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Value</label>
                      <div class="col-sm-10">
                          <input type="number" class="form-control" id="inputValue3" ng-model="order.value" required>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="saveOrder()">Save Order</button>
                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="cancelOrder()">Cancel</button>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom text-center" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <p class="text-muted">&copy; 2015 Copyrights</p>
            <p class="text-muted small">Built using Twitter Bootstrap v3.3.2</p>
        </div>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>

/* site.css */
body {
  padding-top: 70px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.huge {
  font-size: 40px;
}

.panel-green {
  border-color: #5cb85c;
}

.panel-green .panel-heading {
  border-color: #5cb85c;
  color: white;
  background-color: #5cb85c;
}

.panel-green a {
  color: #5cb85c;
}

.panel-green a:hover {
  color: #3d8b3d;
}

.panel-red {
  border-color: #d9534f;
}

.panel-red .panel-heading {
  border-color: #d9534f;
  color: white;
  background-color: #d9534f;
}

.panel-red a {
  color: #d9534f;
}

.panel-red a:hover {
  color: #b52b27;
}

.panel-yellow {
  border-color: #f0ad4e;
}

.panel-yellow .panel-heading {
  border-color: #f0ad4e;
  color: white;
  background-color: #f0ad4e;
}

.panel-yellow a {
  color: #f0ad4e;
}

.panel-yellow a:hover {
  color: #df8a13;
}
```

It's quite annoying when the page moves up and creates a poor user experience.  As this issue doesn't occur when not using Angular I'm inclined to believe that Angular could be the problem, although I cannot see how.

**EDIT**

I've updated the [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/WJolkMctu9V2sOtlvmUt) so that it now uses AngularJS and the page doesn't move up.  I am wondering if this is because I have the `index.html` page being rendered by ASP.NET MVC?

```
<!-- Index.html -->
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" charset="utf-8" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
    <title>Orbit Works</title>
    @Styles.Render( "~/Content/css/themes/bundle", "~/Content/css/app" )
</head>
<body ng-controller="indexController">
    <ptl-header></ptl-header>
    <div class="container">
        <div ui-view></div>
    </div>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom text-center" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <p class="text-muted">&copy; 2015 Michael John Clarke.</p>
            <p class="text-muted small">Built using Twitter Bootstrap v3.3.2 and AngularJS v1.3.9</p>
        </div>
    </nav>
    @Scripts.Render( "~/bundles/script/libraries" )
    @Scripts.Render( "~/bundles/script/app" )
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you confirm you have `padding-top` on the `body`

Comment: Yes `body { padding-top: 70px`; `padding-bottom: 50px`; } is what I have in my site.css file.

Comment: I dont see site.css in the code above?? Is the name correct?

Comment: I have amended the post to include the site.css file.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `autoscroll="untrue"` to the ui-view directive stops the page from scrolling to the child ui-view as described [here](http://expertland.net/question/c51t2yl9254187p4oa64r3235w6x3y4c40f/detail.html).

```
<div ui-view autoscroll="untrue"></div>
```